# Is there method how to integrate StructuredTextEditor in ViewPart or just simple widget?

Tags: xml, eclipse-plugin, integrate, styledtext

We are developing Eclipse plagin project. When you select object into Editor Area properties displays in viewpart below editor.  Viewpart contains textbox with XML data.
Is there method how to integrate StructuredTextEditor in ViewPart or in any simple widget?

Answer (score 1):

i`ve used StructuredTextViewr for this task.
String str = "Yuuupi ";

```
 _document = new Document();
 _document.set(str);    

_sourceViewer = new StructuredTextViewer(
    this,
    ruler,
    overviewRuler,
    true,
    styles)
  {

    @Override
    public void setDocument(IDocument document)
    {

      if (document instanceof IStructuredDocument)
      {
        super.setDocument(document);
      }
      else if (document != null)
      {
        String contentTypeID = ContentTypeIdForXML.ContentTypeID_XML;
        IStructuredModel scratchModel = StructuredModelManager.getModelManager()
            .createUnManagedStructuredModelFor(contentTypeID);

        IDocument newDocument = scratchModel.getStructuredDocument();
        String s = document.get();
        newDocument.set(s);
        super.setDocument(newDocument);
      }
      else
      {
        super.setDocument(null);
      }
    }
  };

_sourceViewer.configure(new org.eclipse.wst.xml.ui.StructuredTextViewerConfigurationXML());

_sourceViewer.setDocument(_document);
_sourceViewer.getControl().setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL,
    SWT.FILL,
    true,
    true));
```